# Cannot make a pull request using git command

Tags: git, github

I am having troubles using pull request using the git command line. Let's say I have a branch called 'stable' that acts like my master branch. So I have a branch called 'mybranch' coming out of stable. I update my code in 'mybranch' and now I want to make a pull request for my branch to stable using the git bash command line. I use github as my git repo. I tried the following:

```
git checkout stable
```

which makes me to be on the stable branch. To make a pull request for my branch i use the following command:

```
git pull origin mybranch
```

and then, I update the stable branch to the github repo as:
    git push origin stable
that pushes my 'stable' branch on github. However, I cannot see my branch being merged or being pulled to the stable branch. I don't know If I am doing something wrong. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

To merge mybranch to stable, just using

```
git commit -m 'last comment'
git checkout stable
git merge mybranch
```

Comment: I don't want a merge. I want to have a pull request and then have it merged using the command line. Is this possible ? I am new to git and I am not sure about it.

Comment: @noobcoder You should know of pull request https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests, that just another way of `merge code`, after mybranch get pulled, you should merge them, then push the `stable` branch to github.com.

Answer (score 0):

Phew! You have mixed a lot of things :-)

1. "git pull" is different from github pull-requests
2. what I udnerstand from your question is:

   - you need to create a branch ( git checkout -b mybranch )
   - update some code there ( edit any file )
   - add the changes to stage ( git add "filename" )
   - commit them ( git commit -m "message for commit" )
   - push the branch to github ( push push origin mybranch )
   - go to github.com and [create a request to get your code reviewed in github](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests) ( read: pull-request )
   - above step can also be done using command line using "[github hub](https://github.com/github/hub)"
   - merge your mybranch to stable from github web interface or using "github hub"
   - come back to stable branch ( git checkout stable )
   - pull the latest changes for your stable branch ( git pull )

Caution: Too much mixing of concepts is very injurious to health :)